# Move existing file entries to project filter folders with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a C++ Visual Studio project.

I created a filter for all the headers and one for sources files. My files are in a folder with many sub folders.

Is there a way to add recursively all files *.h in my header folder and all the *.cpp in the source folder ?

My project :

[image]

Comment: You can directly manipulate the `.vcxproj` and `.vcxproj.filters` files using a XSLT transformation. Other than that there's no way besides handle each entry manually IIRC.

Comment: You want to add files to some project, not to the Visual Studio compiler. Your title is confusing.

Comment: @user0042 I have something like 200 files in 20 folders, can you tell me more about editing the `.vcxproj` ?

Comment: Before you do something in shared projects, be sure your changes get persisted. See [This bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/43104/problem-with-filters-in-c-shared-items-projects.html) in Visual Studio (perhaps only 2017).

Comment: @A.Pissicat These files have XML format. I'm not sure, but I think Microsoft even published the XSD schema for them. The rest is to learn XSLT and how to write transformation scripts. I'm not sure how far the Project window supports selecting files and drag and drop between folders.

Comment: Just a side note - have you tried drag-drop folder directly to the solution explorer tree? Sure it's one-timer, but it might help you.

Comment: I've always found it best to ditch the filter view and go with the "show all files " view and then just structure your directories in the appropriate way.

Comment: @vasek I've try drag and drop but it did not work. Maybe because it's a C++ project.

Comment: @A.Pissicat I just tried that out with my VS2017 installation. Drag and drop between filter folders is supported (I'm pretty sure also for VS2015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution for your problem seems to select each of the file entries in the *Project-Explorer* view, and drag and drop them to the filter folder you want them appearing.

Regarding to add new items you can select multiple files from the open file dialog, but you need to address each subdirectory separately.

---

Another option I could think of is to edit the `.vxcproj.filters` file directly in an appropriate text editor, or with a (XML) text processing tool.

If I open my projects `.vxcproj.filters` file in Notepad++ the relevant snippets look like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Text Include="ReadMe.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="targetver.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="Registry.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="CommandId.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="CommandBase.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="Command1.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="Command2.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="CRTPSelfRegister.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
```